.NET MAUI - Split View AppShell / Static Map Layout
I'm building an app in .NET MAUI that currently uses AppShell for navigation and works well when used with a phone or tablet both locked to portait mode. There is a new requirement coming that will allow the user to use the same app on a tablet in landscape mode which will then present a split screen view. On the left would be the application running exactly how it does currently using AppShell and on the right would a static map control. The user should be able to navigate through the app on the left side normally while the right side remains unchanged. Is there a way I can achieve this goal and still take advantage of AppShell navigation? Or am I going to need to switch to NavigationPages? Or is this even possible?
I've tried creating a tablet-specific AppShell file that loads if the device is of the tablet idiom. It defines a singular ShellContent where the split screen is defined. I am overriding navigation in the AppShell codebehind to essentially transplant page content to the ContentView defined in the ShellContent and that sorta works however I lose benefits of AppShell for back navigation. Am I on the right track here? Any other suggestions that might work in the AppShell vein? Or maybe rethink it using NavigationPages or something else? I am aware of the TwoPaneView in MAUI but I'm not sure if this is going to help me achieve my goal.
Thanks in advance for any suggestions you might have.

I have found a suitable solution for this that involves intercepting normal AppShell navigation to transplant the content of new ContentPages into predefined ContentViews within a singular ShellContent. I have to manually manage a page stack since I cannot rely on AppShell.
I have a test project on my github showing how I did everything:
https://github.com/timdog/AppShellSplitScreen

You can refer to the following sloution:
Donwnload the official code sample of TwoPaneView. On this base, to add NewPage1 and NewPage2 to root directory, also ViewModels folder within MainPageViewModel:

Add this to MainPage.xaml:
                   .....
                    <Button Text="Reset TwoPaneView" Clicked="OnReset"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                    //Add a btn 
                    <Button Text="Back" Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>
 
                </VerticalStackLayout>
           </ScrollView>
       </foldable:TwoPaneView.Pane2>
     </foldable:TwoPaneView>
</ContentPage>

Codebehind:
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
 
     BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
     ......

MainPageViewModel:
public class MainPageViewModel
{
    public Command BackCommand { get; }
 
    public MainPageViewModel() { BackCommand = new Command(OnBackClicked); }
 
    private async void OnBackClicked(object obj)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(NewPage1)}");
    }
}

NewPage1.xaml:
<ContentPage ....>
   <VerticalStackLayout>
       <Label 
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />

       <Button Text="GoToTwoTwoPaneView" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
   </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>

NewPage1.xaml.cs:
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
}

AppShell:
<Shell ....>
   <!--<ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />-->
   <ShellContent Title="MainPage" Route="MainPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"/>
   <FlyoutItem >
       <ShellContent Title="NewPage1" Route="NewPage1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}" />
       <ShellContent Title="NewPage2" Route="NewPage2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage2}" />
   </FlyoutItem>
</Shell>

On this way, you keep benefits of AppShell for back navigation.

Thanks. I will give this a try tonight.

I've tried your suggestions and this is not the solution I'm looking for. When I navigate between pages with your code changes the two panel view goes away and is replaced with a single shell content page. What I need is for one pane to show shell content and change with navigation and the other pane would always stay the same no matter what.

*What I need is for one pane to show shell content and change with navigation and the other pane would always stay the same no matter what. * For MAUI, and also for TwoPaneView, it can't contain Shell or TabbedPage.
